# How to print hyperlinks on Edge?

Tags: html, angular, hyperlink, microsoft-edge

I used `window.print()` function and saved to a .pdf file.
Inside the page I've saved there is a `<a href="www.example.com">` tag. When I'm downloading the file from **Chrome** the link works and it opens the right page. When downloading it from **Edge** it won't work and stays as a simple text.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I tested and reproduced the issue. I think we can only use some plugins to generate the pdf to get the href link working in Edge Legacy.

You could use [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to generate the PDF. Use [`.textWithLink()`](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-annotations.html#~textWithLink) to mimic standard HTML hyperlinks:

```
doc.textWithLink(text, x, y, { url: url });
```

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt'); 
        doc.textWithLink('link', 20, 30, { url: 'http://www.google.com' });
        doc.save("info.pdf");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
My intention is to print the page, as a result one of the options is to save over a .pdf file. I can't see how I can use this library in the window.print() process.

Comment: You're welcome. I use this library because I want to find a workaround of `window.print()`. As `window.print()` can't print a pdf file with working links on Edge so the solution is to find another way to replace it. Tihs library can also generate pdf file and print the whole page.